# Deleting rows with value of checkboxes

Tags: php, html, checkbox, mysqli

I'm having problems with deleting rows from the DB with checkboxes. I don't know how to delete multitple rows from the DB with checkboxes. The problem is that when I press delete it will only delete one.

My PHP code:

```
  // Here I didn't know how to put the value of all checkboxes into one variable.
  $intChk = $_POST['chk'];
  /* ..... */
   foreach($intChk as $intRows)
{
    // Starting the process to delete the selected rows.
      $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM follow WHERE id = ?");
      $stmt->bind_param('s', $intChk);
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->close();
    }
```

My HTML code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chk" class="checkbox" value="<?php echo $followId; ?>" name="chk[]">
```

Thank you for your helping!

Comment: You can pass array of id's via POST and use `foreach` loop...

Comment: Well, for starters, if you want to delete several records based on the checkbox value, you should collect all checkbox id's that were checked for delete. So how you do that? You should use JavaScript. Maybe jQuery or other JS library.

Comment: @Leron if you create several checkbox inputs in HTML with the SAME name but different values it will be visible as an array in PHP $_POST variable. I don't see any sense to use JS library...

Comment: Barell thank you, I used a foreach loop and it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<?php
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM follow WHERE id = ?");
foreach($_POST['chk'] as $checkbox) {
          $stmt->bind_param('s', intval($checkbox));
          $stmt->execute();
}
$stmt->close();
```